Vim highlighting problems with large files
If I open a large file (using that term generously, like ~1000 lines is enough) in vim, and jump somewhere, I sometimes get highlighting that ignores text off screen. For example, if I jump to the end of a large while loop (in sh highlighting, but I have had the same type of problem with C highlighting), the "done" will be marked red as if it does not actually terminate a loop. It is like the program is not looking far enough back to properly contextualize what I am currently looking at. On the other hand, if I go to the start of the loop and 'j' my way down, it will properly highlight. Is there any way to fix this?

Does Ctrl-L help?

@muru, no it does not.

Use this command for a temporary fix: :syntax sync minlines=500
For a more permanent solution, add the following line to your .vimrc file:
syntax sync minlines=500

Also check this post if vim slows down.

The original behavior was hard to predict, so I can't say for sure, but this appears to have fixed it. Thanks!
